# -Xss1m not being used

Tags: java, applet, jvm

I'm trying to user `-Xss1m` option but it didn't look like the option was being used.

I did the following steps:

1. Add a runtime parameter -Xss1m
2. Open my java applet
3. Dump system and deployment properties (press on "s" in java console)
4. Check the value of `javaplugin.vm.options` (contains only `-Djnlp.packEnabled=true`)

enviroment details:

```
java -d64 -version
```

Got the response of:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b13)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: `-Xss1m` sets the stack size to 1 MB. It does not set a system property (you set system properties with `-Dname=value`, so you will not see this if you list the system properties.

Comment: Thank you Jesper for the answer.
But in another enviroment (java-32) I can see it: 
javaplugin.vm.options =  "-Xss1m" "-Djnlp.packEnabled=true"

Comment: Memory in a JNLP launched applet is best done in the resources element, e.g. `<j2se version="1.3" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="128m"/>`